# batch execution from access

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to execute a batch file from my access code. I use following code:

```
Open vPath & "\FtpComm.txt" For Output As fNum
Connexion (fNum) 'function printing connexion info
Print #fNum, "put " & vFile & " Temp.mdb"  'vFile = filename + full path
Deconnexion (fNum) 'function printing deconnexion info
Close fNum
Open vPath & "\doFtp.bat" For Output As batFileHandle 'vPath = full path
Print #batFileHandle, "ftps -a -s:" & vPath & "\FtpComm.txt >" & vPath & "\output.txt"     
Close batFileHandle
RetVal = ExecCmd(vPath & "\doFtp.bat")

Public Function ExecCmd(cmdstr As String) As Long
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ExecCmd = wsh.Run(cmdstr, 0, True)
End Function
```

The batch file is not executed but an empty output.txt file is created.
I used the exact same code for ftp.exe instead of ftps.exe and it worked without problem. The batch file is correctly created, when I execute it manually it works fine.

I don't understand what changed as in the documentation of MOVEit Freely (ftps.exe) they say you only have to change ftp into ftps, all other aspects are the same.

Comment: Is FTPS.EXE in your PATH? FTP.EXE is a standard executable and hence should work, but FTPS.EXE needs to be in a directory on your PATH or in the INVOKING Process's current directory to be located.

Comment: yes i placed it in the PATH and it works. if I do ftps in the cmd it starts running correctly

Comment: Fine - I've just entered an answer - if you'd care to accept it, we're all done!

Comment: But my problem is not solved... i had already placed it in the PATH and if I manually try to execute ftps from the command it works but from my access program somethings going wrong...

Comment: So - does your ACCESS program work if you specify `FTP.EXE` but not if you specify `FTPS.EXE`, or does it fail regardless of the executable you point it to?

Comment: it works with ftp.exe but not ftps.exe

Comment: I'd try copying FTPS.EXE into the same directory/ies as FTP.EXE. Since you're executing `FTP` and not `FTP.EXE` specifically, is there a `FTP.BAT` or `FTP.COM` in your path? If `FTP.BAT` exists, then it will be being executed rather than `FTP.EXE`. All you'd need to do then is copy FTP.BAT to FTPS.BAT and adjust FTPS.BAT to suit. Since it's urgent that's a patch-job that may work - fix it up according to Hoyle later.

Comment: There is no FTP.COM or FTP.BAT. It's only making it worse. When I had ftps.exe in a directory and this directory added to the path I could open the cmd, type ftps and give commands which worked. Now he doesn't recognize ftps any more. What I don't understand is if it is a problem with the PATH how come if I click manually on the Batch file created by my access code it works? My problem is if I use the rest of the code to execute it,it doesn't execute properly but only creates an empty output.txt file and doesn't do the ftps commands But when I used ftp in my access code it all worked perfectly

Comment: For a reason I cannot explain, when I changed the path and ftps.exe back to where they were it solved the problem and now it is all working perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing `FTPS.EXE` in your path should solve the problem.